# Formatting the columns of a table in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to use LaTeX for documentation. I am unable to format the table. Please refer the following snippet of code.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{| m{3cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm}| m{3cm} | m{3cm} |}
\hline
Software Project & a_a & b_b & c_b & d_b \\
\hline
Organic &   2.4 &  1.05   & 2.5 & 0.38\\
\hline
Semi-detached & 3.0 &  1.12  & 2.5 & 0.35\\
 \hline
 Embedded & 3.6 &  1.20   & 2.5 & 0.32\\
 \hline
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to reach?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like the code+screenshot I posted below?

If that fits, remember what follows:

1. check to have `\usepackage{array}` in your preamble;
2. use `\centering` instead of nesting `tabular` into `center` into `table`;
3. review the width of the columns;
4. `a_a` only works in math mode: `$a_a$`;
5. check to have your environments closed properly (`\end{tabular}`, etc. are missing in the code you pasted in your question).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{| m{3.5cm} | m{1.5cm} | m{1.5cm} | m{1.5cm} | m{1.5cm} |}
    \hline
    Software Project & $a_a$ & $b_b$ & $c_b$ & $d_b$\\
    \hline
    Organic & 2.4 & 1.05 & 2.5 & 0.38\\
    \hline
    Semi-detached & 3.0 & 1.12 & 2.5 & 0.35\\
    \hline
    Embedded & 3.6 & 1.20 & 2.5 & 0.32\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of centered tabular in A4 paper]

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly for me.